# Replacing duplicate rows in a column in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app where the user can choose one or several analyses depending on water type. They should able to choose as many analyses as they wish for each water type, independently of one another. For example, they should be able to choose 2 analyses in freshwater, and three in seawater. In this example, the table would ideally look like this:

```
  Freshwater Saltwater
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 pH         pH       
2 turbidity  salinity 
3 -          turbidity
```

But I am having issues formatting my table since my `data.frame` is dynamic. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

AnalysisChoices = c("pH", "salinity","turbidity")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(box(pickerInput( 
    
    inputId = "anaFW",
    label = "Analysis 2",
    choices =AnalysisChoices,
    
    multiple = T,
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
    
    pickerInput(
      
      inputId = "anaSea",
      label = "Analysis 1 ",
      choices = AnalysisChoices,
      multiple = T,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)))
   ,
    
    
  fluidRow( DT::dataTableOutput ("analysisTbl"),
    style = "  overflow-y: scroll;
                   overflow-x: scroll;"
  ) ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    DataAnalysis = reactive({
      df2<- data.frame(
        
        Freshwater = if (length(input$anaFW) == 0) {
          Freshwater = ""
          
        }
        else {
          Freshwater = input$anaFW
          
        },
        SeaWater = if (length(input$anaSea) == 0) {
          SeaWater = ""
        }
        else {
          SeaWater = input$anaSea
        })
      return(list(df2 = (df2)))
      
      
     
   
      
    })
    output$analysisTbl <- renderDataTable({DataAnalysis()$df2})


} )
```

If I have one analysis in one of the options and several on the other option, the analysis in the first option will be repeated in the next rows. If I try the previous example (2 options for one water type and 3 for the other), then I will get an error message since the function won't know how to populate the empty rows. How can I replace the empty cells with `-` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

################ cbind datasets with different number of rows  ######
cbindPad <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args,nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      if (ncol(x)==0) {
        return(padTemp)
      } else {
        return(rbind(x,padTemp))
      }
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
  return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}

AnalysisChoices = c("pH", "salinity","turbidity")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(box(pickerInput( 
    
    inputId = "anaFW",
    label = "Analysis 2",
    choices =AnalysisChoices,
    
    multiple = T,
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
    
    pickerInput(
      
      inputId = "anaSea",
      label = "Analysis 1 ",
      choices = AnalysisChoices,
      multiple = T,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)))
    ,
    
    
    fluidRow( DT::dataTableOutput ("analysisTbl"),
              style = "  overflow-y: scroll;
                   overflow-x: scroll;"
    ) ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    DataAnalysis = reactive({
      df1<- data.frame(
        Freshwater = if (length(input$anaFW) == 0) {
          Freshwater = ""
        }
        else {
          Freshwater = input$anaFW
        })
      
      df2 <- data.frame(
        SeaWater = if (length(input$anaSea) == 0) {
          SeaWater = ""
        }
        else {
          SeaWater = input$anaSea
        })
      
      df <- cbindPad(df1,df2)
      return(df)
      
    })
    
    output$analysisTbl <- renderDataTable({DataAnalysis()})
    
  } )
```

[image: output]